# Axios - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' - CORS

Tags: javascript, axios, cors

I'm building a JavaScript app which uses an external API.
To get the data, I use axios, but whenever I make a request it returns a CORS error:

> "No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header set".

Now, a temporary solution is to add a third part proxy in front of the API URL (for example https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com), and it works just fine, but I don't really want to depend on a third part server and would like to handle it inside my own app.

I've tried pretty much everything and still can't get it to work. I've used axios response interceptors to attach required headers to the response, but it just doesn't work.

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(res => {
  res.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
  res.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
  res.headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = 'POST'
  return res;
})
```

My server.js file looks something like this

```js
const express = require('express')
const serveStatic = require('serve-static')
const path = require('path')
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express()

app.use('/', serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')))
app.use(cors());

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080
app.listen(port, () => console.log("starting on port 8080"));
```

Any solutions on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to invert the two lines :

```
app.use(cors());
app.use('/', serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));
```

Tell me if it works

By the way your interceptors is useless, you can remove it :

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(...
```

Comment: I inverted the lines and the preflight still gets triggered and gives me a cors error, unfortunately.

I deleted all the interceptors and common headers except one of them, and that's my api-key header.

Comment: Try two things : 1) replace `cors()` by `cors({origin: true})` 2) add `withCredentials: true`  (see axios docs https://github.com/axios/axios). If one of the two works i will replace my response above

Comment: still nothing... and i'm not sure if it matters but the implementation of the API includes a POST request (that's what's returning a CORS error actually, cause it's the first request to be sent)

Comment: with cors({origin: true}) can you check if OPTIONS request or POST request is blocking. and can you provide Request and Response headers coming from Chrome on the blocked request

Comment: The POST request is a blocking one, if I'm not mistaken. Altough the OPTIONS request doesn't contain Access-Cotrol-Allow-Origin header as well.

Comment: Here is what I get:
the console logs: https://i.imgur.com/IYnCKaH.png
options request: https://i.imgur.com/iPk9awB.png
blocking (POST) request to the API: https://i.imgur.com/6mdnDt4.png

I've just censored the API provider cause I don't know if it's against the rules to post it here.

Btw, both cors({ origin: true }) and axios "withCredentials: true" are set while making this request.

Comment: try to add an `app.post('/test', (req, res) => {res.json({ok: 1});})` just below `app.use(cors({origin: true}));` and call this POST endpoint instead of your endpoint. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header should be present ...

Comment: You're right. The header is there (Access-Cotrol-Allow-Origin) and it's set to my web site URL, when I make request to a /test route. But just can't quite figure out how to do it with my API.